NoClassDefFoundError and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate in SpringBoot project
I am trying to create a Kafka Producer to publish some data to topic. When I build my project using "mvn clean install" it builds successfully but the issue is when I try to deploy the jar on docker it fails with below error related to Kafka dependency,
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate
Note : I am using Java 17 with maven version 3.9.6. Sppring Boot version is 3.1.5
Kafka Dependency added in pom.xml is as below,`
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

